# apache tiles 2 JSPException including path

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets, tiles

I create a java web application with using Hibernate framework. 
In WEB-INF, I created a new file: tiles-defs.xml, the below is the content in it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="Page" template="/share/layout.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="title" value="Page" />
         <put-attribute name="header" value="/share/header.jsp" />  
    </definition>
    <definition name="Index" extends="Page">
         <put-attribute name="title" value="Vnmart" />
         <put-attribute name="main" value="/home/IndexContent.jsp"/>
    </definition>    
</tiles-definitions>
```

And in web.xml, I added some rows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In web pages folder, I created home folder to contain 2 jsp files: Index.jsp and IndexContent.jsp.
Index.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="Index"/>
```

And IndexContent.jsp:

```
<div>Home</div>
```

After that, I created a controller package, and add new Home servlet:

```
String view = "home/Index.jsp";
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(view);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

But when I ran, apache said: 'HTTP Status 404 - /Project2/' (Project2 is name of project). And then, I checked in Apache Tomcat Log, I found an error:

> 'SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Home] in context with path
>   [/Project2] threw exception
>   [org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: JSPException including
>   path '/layouts/layoutfront.jsp'.] with root cause
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: File
>   "/home/IndexContent.jsp" not found'

I have no ideas about this, I followed some tutorial how to working with tiles, but I'm still get stuck.

Comment: /home/IndexContent.jsp exists?

Comment: http://sys-exit.blogspot.com/2013/03/apache-tiles-3-useattribute.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was asked a year ago, but if anyone runs into the same issue here is how I fixed it. If the definition tag's name parameter and add-attribute tag's value parameter are the same I think it throws a stackoverflow error message. When I change those names, it worked fine for me.

```
<definition name="Page" template="/share/layout.jsp"><put-attribute name="title" value="Page xyz" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, i was struggling with this problem and you saved my day. Is it a bug or something else.

Comment: Thanks Dear for answer. It is awesome ^_^